# Get product category, link,price,product description from Amazon or FlipKart like website of a particular seller. Just Like web Crawler\spiderbot

Tags: php, python, asp.net, ruby-on-rails, web-crawler

Want to get list of all categories, product, price, description for only a particular seller from amazon. Any coding language. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can any one suggest I there is any api that can be used for amazon?

Answer (score 0):

You can use gem named as `Mechanize`
https://github.com/sparklemotion/mechanize.

For getting URL - go to amazon, click on any seller. copy the url in get action and query.

This Solution is Ruby based